# jQuery .on() and ajax

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm adding elements to a page using the jQuery ajax function, on success I get the response from the server and assign it to an element, like so:

```
$('#element').html(response);
```

Then I need jQuery to consider the newly added element. My problem is that it is not in the DOM, so I thought of using `.on()`:

```
$(".remove").on("click", function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

But this does not work. Well, it does work, but only on elements that were loaded in the first place with the page, not with the new ones. Shouldn't `.on()` consider also the "new elements"?

PS actually the "click" event is just for testing, I would need the function to run on mouseover, but as of now I'm trying to understand how to work with new DOM elements added through AJAX.

Comment: You need to delegate the event handler higher up the DOM tree. Read the [`.on()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate it. *Delegate it.* ***Delegate it.***

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e){
    /*
       do something when *any* `.remove` element is clicked
       in the document, now and in the future.
    */
});
```

Comment: Oh thank's so much!! I still don't get (and did not get when I read the documentation) what the the delegate does. I mean, I thought I had to link the listener to my `.remove` css class, then set the event (`click`), and call the function. So since `.on()` has to be linked to the document, the delegate tells which element of the DOM to look for?

Comment: @ghego1 you can delegate from **any** parent element (doesn't have to be `document`)